# What is server architecture and server setup?

Tags: architecture, server

This is kind of a broad question and i'm not sure about whether this is the right place to be asking it, but I couldn't really determine a better site on the stack exchange sites list.

when you say server setup? is it the software that you have used to run your website? 
like

- apache2
- php5.4
- mysql

and when you say server architecture, is it the specifications of your webserver?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Server Architecture** determines the architecture and processes within the server. There are traditionally two competitive server architectures--one is based on threads, the other on events. Over time, more sophisticated variants emerged, sometimes combining both approaches. There has been a long controversy, whether threads or events are generally the better fundament for high performance web servers . After more than a decade, this argument has been now reinforced, thanks to new scalability challenges and the trend towards multi-core CPUs.

**Server Setup** determines how the user is connected to the server. Here is a list of commonly used server setups, with a short description of each

1. Everything On One Server - The entire environment resides on a single server. For a typical web application, that would include the web server, application server, and database server. A common variation of this setup is a LAMP stack, which stands for Linux, Apache, MySQL, and PHP, on a single server.
2. Separate Database Server - The database management system (DBMS) can be separated from the rest of the environment to eliminate the resource contention between the application and the database, and to increase security by removing the database from the DMZ, or public internet.
3. Load Balancer (Reverse Proxy) - Load balancers can be added to a server environment to improve performance and reliability by distributing the workload across multiple servers. If one of the servers that is load balanced fails, the other servers will handle the incoming traffic until the failed server becomes healthy again. It can also be used to serve multiple applications through the same domain and port, by using a layer 7 (application layer) reverse proxy.
4. HTTP Accelerator (Caching Reverse Proxy) - An HTTP accelerator, or caching HTTP reverse proxy, can be used to reduce the time it takes to serve content to a user through a variety of techniques. The main technique employed with an HTTP accelerator is caching responses from a web or application server in memory, so future requests for the same content can be served quickly, with less unnecessary interaction with the web or application servers.
5. Master-Slave Database Replication - One way to improve performance of a database system that performs many reads compared to writes, such as a CMS, is to use master-slave database replication. Master-slave replication requires a master and one or more slave nodes. In this setup, all updates are sent to the master node and reads can be distributed across all nodes.

For more info - https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/5-common-server-setups-for-your-web-application

Comment: No problem @Hitori